# Give an example of a homomorphism $f : R\to S$ such that $R$ has an identity but $S$ does not

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does this contradict part 4 of theorem 3.10 (if $R$ is a ring with identity, and $f$ is surjective, then $S$ is a ring with identity $f(1_R).$

I believe I have an answer to this, $R=\mathbb Z$ and $S$ being the subset of $2\times2$ matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ a & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $f$ being the zero homomorphism. Clearly $R$ has identity and $S$ doesn't, but this doesn't contradict the theorem because the zero homomorphism is not surjective. However, what if we have the function $f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. $f$ seems to be surjective, as every element of $S$ is mapped to by some element of $R$, and also seems to contradict the theorem, since $f(1) \ne \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Theorem 3.10 of what?

Comment: The part of the theorem referenced is in the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, but 3.10 of what book or paper?

Comment: Abstract Algebra An Introduction 3rd Ed, Thomas Hungerford

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity for your $S$ is $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$.
The theorem is ok and your example is not a counter example. The mentioned thheorem says that the identity of
$R$ is mapped into identity of the image of $f$.

Comment: Ah ok. What about the counterexample  $f : Z \to 2Z$, where $f(x)=2x$? $2Z$ definitely does not have identity, but $f(x)=2x$ seems to be surjective.

Comment: @10432 But that $f$ isn't a ring homomorphism.

Comment: From the title of the question I guess that you are looking for a homomorphisms. $f:{\mathbb Z} \to 2{\mathbb Z}$ which is given by $f(x)=2x$ is not a homomorphism: f(xy)=2xy\ne 2x\cdot 2y=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: Right, that is obvious. Thanks everyone for clearing up my confusion.